# Set image color in AppCompatImageButton or imageview in android

Tags: android

How to set image color in AppCompatImageButton in andoidx ? Because I tried with setting color background-tint in xml in AppCompatImageButton but it is not setting . Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Attach your xml

Comment: Is my answer what you want or not?

Answer (score 3):

You should tint to change the color of the image,

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Backgroundtint"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will be output:

[image]

I think you mean Button not Imagebutton, because you can't change color of an image in XML.